# How can I dynamically inject a partial view (or code) based on the current page (MVC3/Razor)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm not able to get a clear answer on my problem: I want to have one partial view but have 3 distinct code blocks within the partial with similar (not exactly the same) content. So that whatever view page is loaded will determine which of the 3 code blocks is displayed in the partial view.

I did something similar back in MVC2, but it was on the controller level (controller determined which of the 3 code blocks was displayed). Now I have a need to go deeper and do it on the page level.

I understand that a bunch of `if/else` statements in a view is not the MVC convention. But honestly, that's the only way I know how to do it. An alternative is to keep this `if/else` logic and create more than one controller and keep doing it the old way.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your partial view looks something like this

```
<div>...Generic stuff used all the time...</div>
...
<div>...special block used only in some circumstances...</div>
...
<div>...another special block used only in some other circumstance...</div>
...etc...
```

You can design a ViewModel class which has some properties to determine which block of code to show

e.g.

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
   public bool ShowBlockOne { get; set; }
   public bool ShowBlockTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Then, your partial view would look something like this

```
@model MyViewModel 
<div>...Generic stuff used all the time...</div>
...
@if (Model.ShowBlockOne) {
    <div>...special block used only in some circumstances...</div>
}
...
@if (Model.ShowBlockTwo) {
    <div>...another special block used only in some other circumstance...</div>
}
...etc...
```

And the views calling the Partial View would use `Html.RenderPartial`, and would pass a MyViewModel with the properties set, depending upon what they wanted to show.  e.g.

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("MyPartial", new MyViewModel { ShowBlockOne = true } ); }
```

You should be able to use some variation of this.

As you will be aware, you should keep logic to a minimum in your Views, but the occasional if/then is OK.

Comment: This looks like a very elegant solution, and I am going to try it over using the @helper syntax for razor (which requires using `/App_Code/` and will require a special binder if I want to using any of the stock razor `@Html.Helpers`). I believe for static HTML that wouldn't ordinarily be a problem, but StanK's solution obviates the need to worry about if I later decide to do more logic within the partial.

Comment: OOC, is there a way to do something like this automatically based on what page is being viewed? As I mentioned, I was able to do this with a `ControllerContext` and automatically pick a view based on what Controller was working.

Comment: You _could_ potentially have the partial view check the context in which it is invoked, but this is probably not a good idea.  Ideally, the partial view shouldn't depend on what is rendering it - it should only depend on it's Model and logic in the View should be kept to an absolute minimum.

Answer (score 4):

There's at least 4 ways you could do this.

1. If/Else, like @StanK mentions
2. Invoke a child action from the main view. Build logic into the action to render a different partial based on said logic.
3. Create a custom HTML helper which extends @Html.Partial by checking your custom logic before rendering a different partial (essentially moving the if/else to the HTML helper)
4. Add some OO to your model. Create an abstract class, and a deriving class for each of the 3 "similar, but different" code blocks, and a matching editor template for each. Then in your main view, call @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomethingDeclaredAbstract) and MVC will pick the right template.

Hard to advise on which one, given you haven't supplied much code and you haven't said what's different about the 3 pieces of content.

I usually go with option 4 because it's the cleanest and most versatile.

Comment: The content is just that, static Html content. In fact, most times the content is the same, but within it I might make a change for a particular service. So, for example, block one might say "Thank you for choosing [Service 1]" and include more text about Service 1. Then block to would say "Thank you for choosing [Service 2]" and include more text about Service 2. Each code block also contains distinct `@Html.ActionLink`'s, but otherwise no other "code".

Comment: Otherwise, +1 for suggestions. I don't have edit privileges, but I discovered another method (which is similar to your #3 suggestion): Using the @helper syntax within razor. I can create a @helper file in `/App_Code/` each with a distinct code block name, and then simply use templates to `@RenderSection`. Not as elegant, but it certainly gives me finer control over a page. The only problem is using `/App_Code/` and having to use a custom binder if I want to do any real "coding".

Comment: I would have edited your answer to include @helper syntax with razor as a viable option as I wound up writing in my comments instead. Because of my low reputation, I cannot "edit" questions/answers (well, now that I read the fineprint I could but it would have to be peer reviewed which might never happen - hence why I put the option in the comment).